# Github profile Read.md file not displayed on my profile

Tags: github

I wanted to create a good profile section for my github account and went in and made a repo with the same name as my github account id. Built a good readme section and committed the changes into the repo and went on to check my updated profile section. But I was not able to find any changes in my profile section (the readme file not displayed there) even after all of this. I'm attaching a link to my profile and relevant screenshots for reference, could anyone help me out with this ?

Link to github profile: https://github.com/akshayrajeevnambiar

Screenshots:
[github profile readme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTkTM.png)
[github profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Jgx.png)

I have tried updating my readme and refreshing the browser but nothing seems to work, also tried searching on the web for similar issues but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.